# Fetch Build Statistics for an Application from Bamboo REST API

Tags: build, bamboo

I am looking for the `Bamboo REST API` which give us all recent `Build Activity` of an Application within a time-frame like all build of `Last_7_Days`, `Last_1_Day`, `Last_30_Days` etc. Similar to the report we get in Bamboo UI for **Build Activity** of a **Plan**. In Bamboo Report we have three section `Chart`, `Data Table` and `Builds`. We have  [REST API](https://developer.atlassian.com/bamboodev/rest-apis/bamboo-rest-resources#BambooRESTResources-ChartService) for `Chart`. But I still couldn't found any REST API to get the `Build Activity`. Report format attached for reference. 
[image]

I tried [Bamboo Chart API](https://developer.atlassian.com/bamboodev/rest-apis/bamboo-rest-resources#BambooRESTResources-ChartService) but its giving output as a chart image.  Does anyone know any Bamboo REST API to fetch Build Activity of an Application?

I will appreciate your help. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

As you have found there are no direct REST APIs for build activity by time period.

I'd use the build REST API (https://developer.atlassian.com/bamboodev/rest-apis/bamboo-rest-resources#BambooRESTResources-BuildService%E2%80%94AllBuilds) and XLST to filter the results by time period.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I couldn't understand `XLST to filter the results by time period`? can you please explain bit more.

Comment: XLST can be used to transform/filter XML (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT).  Here is an example for filtering the given XML on the left to show only those priced above $10 - http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/tryxslt.asp?xmlfile=cdcatalog&xsltfile=cdcatalog_if

Comment: In the example above it applies the filter: <xsl:if test="price>10">.  You could apply the same idea for your date ranges

Comment: Thanks for the explanation :) That's is I am already doing with help of python script. I am getting API output in Json format and while iterating over json. I am comparing `buildStartedTime` with date range.